# Set CI/CD in dbt to test only modified models and new tests

Tags: dbt

I'm new to dbt, and been searching for this answer without success: how can we configure CI/CD to only test for modifications in models and their tests, or addition of new tests?

Comment: What if one of the models that you are changing is affecting a downstream model?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the `manifest.json` from your last full production run, and then you can use the state flag and the state selector to specify only modified models.

https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/methods#the-state-method

https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/guides/understanding-state

As Aleix points out in their comment, usually you will want to run the models downstream of those modified as well.